# How to use typoscript object in fluid template as if condition

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I have a typoscript TEXT object:

```
lib.myid = TEXT
lib.myid.value = 1413
```

And want to use it in a fluid template (for tx_news):

```
<f:for each="{newsItem.categories}" as="category">
    <f:if condition="{category.uid} == {lib.myid}">
        Category ID is the same as myid
    </f:if>
</f:for>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ViewHelper [f:cObject](http://wiki.typo3.org/Fluid#f:cObject). It would look like this:

```
<f:for each="{newsItem.categories}" as="category">
    <f:if condition="{category.uid} == {f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.myid')}">
        Category ID is the same as myid
    </f:if>
</f:for>
```

Alternatively, you can make the value a setting of the news plugin, by setting

```
plugin.tx_news {
    settings {
        valuefromlibrary < lib.myid
    }
}
```

Afterwards, you can access the value using `{settings.valuefromlibrary}` in your template. But beware that the settings are not automatically passed on to partials, so in a partial the value might not be defined. This restriction is circumvented in the default template of EXT:news by passing the `settings`-variable to partials.

Comment: Now I know why sometimes values are saved in settings, even they don't really have something to do with that plugin. I used the cObject, but didn't know I can use it also as Inline Notation. ty

Comment: is there a direct way to access the settings from another plugin as I am currently in? For example I am in a template from `tx_news` but I want to access the settings from `tx_somethingelse`.

Comment: @nbar: The way to pass settings from tx_somethingelse to tx_news it to put this in the `setup.txt` of tx_somethingelse...
```plugin.tx_news {
 settings {
  detail {
   disqusShortname = {$someVarAccessibleFrom_tx_somethingelse}
  }
 }
}```